# Photoshop Javascript to go to the next layer (layer above)

Tags: javascript, action, photoshop, layer

I want to be able to go to the layer above. I have over 3000 files that i need to select the layer above from and I cannot seem to work out how to do it.

It always has a different name too. But i always start from the same layer and it's always in the same position.

I need this to get the contents of a text layer.

Any ideas? I've been at it a while now but my Javascript knowledge is limited.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There might be a smarter way to do this, but the following should work. You can basically tell the layer's z-position by its `itemIndex` property. So once you have that you can search the one with an itemIndex which is one higher than the current one. When you found it, you can make sure it's a text layer and if so, retrieve it's text contents.

```js
var textContent = "";
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var ix = doc.activeLayer.itemIndex;

for(var i = 0; i < doc.layers.length; i++) {

  if(doc.layers[i].itemIndex === ix + 1 && doc.layers[i].kind === LayerKind.TEXT) {
    textContent = doc.layers[i].textItem.contents;
    break;
  }

}

alert("The text content is: " + textContent);
```